# How do I update My chart.js data in react?

Tags: reactjs, charts

I'm new to React, and I'm trying to figure out how to setState to the object, but it doesn't work when I this.setState({ datasets[0].data: }), in the function what do I need to do here??

```
state={
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [{
        data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
        label: "My First dataset",
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        }]
    }

    change = () => {
        this.setState({
            datasets: 
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
      const datasets = prevState.datasets;
      datasets[0].label = newLabel; //you can change particular value this way
      return {datasets};
});
```

What this does is actually make a copy of prevState datasets array of objects and the mutates its value as per the requirement. Once the changes are done, we will setState value with the value of the updated datasets.